# Scan multiple sitemaps with Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

I'm trying to scrap some sitemaps with javascript

Using node v8.11.3 and Axios

For example a snippet of the code is:

```
url: url.resolve(siteurl, 'post_sitemap_1.xml'),
```

However the website has post_sitemap_2.xml that i'd like to scan as well, how can I make that line scan both instead of that single page?

```
 url: url.resolve(siteurl, 'post_sitemap_1.xml' & 'post_sitemap_2.xml'),
```

^ obviously not working - just an example of what I want to achieve.

Alternatively if possible scan any post_sitemap_*.xml that may be added in the future.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Vanilla JS, or Node?  And if Node, what version?

Comment: `'post_sitemap_1.xml' & 'post_sitemap_2.xml'` returns `0` as a result of bitwise ANDing the operands. Please describe your problem clearly and mention the specific tools that are being used. Without this information, this questions is very unlikely to be answered correctly.

Comment: I'm using v8.11.3, and axios

Comment: @PDANGER Then tag the question correctly and [edit] that information in.